# inner classes shouldnt implement serializable

Tags: java, serialization

I was reading Effective Java and came across this paragraph ( a bit dense for me currently). Can someone explain why inner classes should not implement Serializable in more detail?

> Inner classes (Item 22) should not implement Serializable. They use
>     compiler-generated synthetic fields to store references to enclosing instances and to store 
>     values of local variables from enclosing scopes. How these fields correspond to the class 
>     definition is unspecified, as are the names of anonymous and local classes. Therefore, the 
>     default serialized form of an inner class is ill- defined.

Comment: Get a mac using OpenJDK and a linux machine using JRockit (or some other JVM), then create a Serializable inner class and use RMI to pass it between those machines...

Comment: If that works, then try IBM's JDK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So like imagine this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class A {

     private Object mFoo;

     public A(Object foo) {
       mFoo = foo;
     }

     public Serializable getData() {
        String niceString = "Nice String";
        return new B(niceString);
     }

     public class B implements Serializable {
       private Object mBlob;

       public B (Object blob) {
          mBlob = blob;
       }

       public String toString() {
         return String.format("%s-%s-%s", getClass(), mBlob, mFoo);
       }

     }

     public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
       A a = new A("Have a nice Day");
       Serializable s  = a.getData();
       System.out.println("Before:" + s);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);
        ostream.writeObject(s);
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        ByteArrayInputStream bytesIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOut.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream istream = new ObjectInputStream(bytesIn);
        System.out.println("After:" + istream.readObject());
     }
}
```

There virtual constructs that have are for things like `mFoo` in this case. Referencing them in the `toString()` here is possible because this jvm has a reference to the instance of `A` with the "Have a nice Day" string in it. Now if it were static that is a different thing. But without the static this might not be able to be serialized.

```
Before:class A$B-Nice String-Have a nice Day
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: A
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
    at A.main(A.java:35)
```

Now let's modify `B` a little bit to something like:

```
public static class B implements Serializable {

     private Serializable mData2;
     private Object mBlob;

           public B (Object blob) {
              mBlob = blob;
              mData2 = new Serializable() {
                 String data = "Foo";
                 public String toString() {
                  return data;
                 }
              };
           }

           public String toString() {
             return String.format("%s-%s-%s", getClass(), mBlob, mData2);
           }
}
```

Now there is no reference to `A`, `B` has an anonymous class that points back to B since it's technically an inner class. This would be the same problem except B is also Serializable. What's the output. I'm running on hotspot.

```
Before:class A$B-Nice String-Foo
After:class A$B-Nice String-Foo
```

So all parts can be written great! ... but there is still a problem.

**NOTE** it only works because we are controlling a few things.

Let's say instead of the serializing to a buffer and re-reading it in, within the same app we do something probably more useful. Let's say we save the instance of `B` to a file. This is essentially serializing the anonymous inner class outside of the given runtime.

If you were describing the class `B` to someone else what would you call that anonymous inner class? It is anonymous afterall. You would probably call it something that made sense to you and refer to it that way consistently. That's sort of what the sdk/runtime do too. It named it something that wouldn't collide with any of the other class in the classpath. In Hotspot I think it would be named `A.B$1` since it is the first anonymous inner class of `B` (Why this is not 0 indexed has always bothered me). This is an implementation of Hotspot detail I believe though. So if you were to take the same source and compile it with another sdk toolset, and then run the code, and have it deserialize that file, if it didn't call that anonymous inner class the same name, there will probably be a `ClassNotFoundException` thrown and you would be like HUH? HOW? WHERE? and it would be a pain to chase down since who knows when that file was written.

There is a specification for the Serialization format, which is where this sort stems from. Usually there is some sort of magic number to specify the data start and then the class name of the serialized blob, preceded by an `L`, so I think in this case the file would contain something like, `LA.B$1` if compiled and run on Hotspot. So all the runtime can really do when it reads that stream is look for `A.B.$1`, as it has no knowledge of really what runtime, or runtime instance that file came from. (Going off of memory here, so there are a lot of details I am skipping over).